# Slashes in MySQL tables, but using PDO and parameterized queries. Whats up?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Alright, so my code to update my database tables is varying flavours of the following:

```
$query = "
  insert into Comment 
    (Comment, CommentDate, Rating, UserRid) 
  values 
    (:comment, now(), 0, :userrid )" ;

try {           
  $db_conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_server.';dbname='.$db_name, $db_username, $db_password );

  $db_conn->beginTransaction();
  $prep = $db_conn->prepare($query);
  $prep->bindParam(':comment', $comment, PDO::PARAM_STR, 500);
  $prep->bindParam(':userrid', $userrid, PDO::PARAM_INT, 20);
  $prep->execute();

  $db_conn->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e)  {
  $db_conn.rollBack();
  echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
  die();
}
```

In the above, comment comes in via Post from another page.  Userrid is being set properly via a function call.  Everything works properly, except the slashes get added to the table.

Everything I've read says that in order to get around having slashes whenever someone types in an apostrophe that I should be using parameterized queries.  If I'm not mistaken, I'm pretty sure that's what I'm doing.  Am I missing something?  Can anybody let me know what I'm not doing right?

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably ou've [`magic_quotes_gpc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on, you need to do something like this:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc() == true)
{
    $comment = stripslashes($comment);
    $userrid = stripslashes($userrid);
}
```

If you're using PHP 5.3+ you can get rid of all magic quoted variables by placing the following lines of code on the top of your file:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc() === 1)
{
    $_GET = json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode($_GET, JSON_HEX_APOS)), true);
    $_POST = json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode($_POST, JSON_HEX_APOS)), true);
    $_COOKIE = json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode($_COOKIE, JSON_HEX_APOS)), true);
    $_REQUEST = json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode($_REQUEST, JSON_HEX_APOS)), true);
}
```

If you're running a lower version of PHP you should [take a look at this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but after adding that in, I get...

Fatal error: Call to undefined function magic_quotes_gpc() in <insert file path here> on line <blah blah>

Comment: Hey, the link you sent along seemed to get me sorted out.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Michael Beck: I'm sorry, I had a typo. It's fixed now.

Comment: No worries.  That link you sent was extremely helpful.  ;-)  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It prevents you from *having to add them*, but things like [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) will put them in regardless of whether or not they're needed.

Comment: Alright, how do I get rid of them?  As near as I can tell, I'm not using anything in my code that says magic_quotes.