# Error in mysql_real_escape-string function not escaping the special character

Tags: mysql

I'm using the mysql_real_escape_string function to escape the special character from the text to insert the data into the database.If I use variable it is not working.

```
echo  $ab=$_POST['textarea'];
when I print $ab it is showing like the following text;
$ab= ction throws js error we'll special charac
echo $av=mysql_real_escape_string($av);
```

when I pirnt the $av it is showing the following string

```
ction throws js error we'll special charac
```

when I use the $av value in insert query it is insert only half test only "ction throws js error we" in database. Please let me know how can i fix it.

Comment: What happens if you remove the echo part of that line?

Comment: This seems similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128871/slashes-in-mysql-tables-but-using-pdo-and-parameterized-queries-whats-up

Comment: I have written for check the output only. it is showing the string in output.

Answer (score 1):

First of all please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). Use  [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Now if you stick with `mysql_*` extension anyway do something like this

```php
$ab="";
if (isset($_POST['textarea']) && $_POST['textarea']) {
    $ab = $_POST['textarea'];
}
if (!$db = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')) {
    //connection error
} 
if (!mysql_select_db('dbname', $db)) {
    //error selecting db
}
if (!$ab = mysql_real_escape_string($ab)) {
    //error while escaping
}
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO table VALUES('%s')", $ab);
if (!mysql_query($query)) {
    //error executing query
}
```

*Error handling code intentionally omitted for brevity*